# Laravel 5.4 and Slick carousel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5.4, slick.js

I am using laravel 5.4 and I want to use slick.js to create a slider on the top of my page.

But I keep getting the message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):243)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

This is at the bottom of my main template before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
@yield('script')
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

And this is on my page view in the script section at the bottom:

```
@section('script')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.home-slider').slick({
                arrows: false,
                dots: true
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

.home-slider is a div with divs in it containing images. jQuery 3.2.1 is being loaded before all scripts.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you try to use jquery migrate?

Comment: Check that your ".js" files load correctly, ctrl+u and click on file names to see if the address is ok and you don't get 404.

Comment: Included the latest version of jQuery migrate and .js files are checked and loading correctly. No improvements though.